# What design pattern can be followed while implementing API that calls multiple APIs

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, design-patterns

I have just begun exploring the design patterns and implementation of Web APIs.

I have a scenario where one single API requests to a set of APIs in sequence based on a string value.

Eg: let's say I have an API called StartAPI.
This might send request to a subset of APIs (let's call it API_X, API_Y, API_Z, API_T, API_U) based on given string.

Let's assume the below:
If i pass "string1" or "string2" to StartAPI then it should call API_X, API_Z.

If i pass "string3" it calls API_X, API_Z, API_T.

If i pass "string4" it calls all APIs

API_X, API_Z, API_T, API_Y, API_U.

What design pattern can I follow in this case to minimise the if else conditions?

Comment: [Mediator](https://www.dofactory.com/net/mediator-design-pattern) pattern could work for this

Comment: Chain of Responsibility Pattern. You can setup a handler that goes through each API and then back if needed. If the handler is too much then a simple factory pattern will work by passing the string into the factory.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Patterns aren't something you apply just because. They are `a solution to a problem in a context`. The same problem in different circumstances will have different solutions. Quite possibly you don't need any pattern, just a `Dictionary<string,Uri>` to look up the target API based on the keyword string. Or a `switch` expression. If you use Dependency Injection, eg in ASP.NET Core, you can register services by name, so you can retrieve the service/HttpClient you want using its name

Comment: _"What design pattern can I follow in this case to minimise the `if else` conditions?"_ - OOP Design Patterns are not concerned with the syntax of control-flow.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that Chain of Responsibity pattern is way to go. [As wiki says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern):

> the chain-of-responsibility pattern is a behavioral design pattern
> consisting of a source of command objects and a series of processing
> objects.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern) Each processing object contains logic that defines the
> types of command objects that it can handle; the rest are passed to
> the next processing object in the chain. A mechanism also exists for
> adding new processing objects to the end of this chain.

So let me show an example how code would look like. Let's start from classes which define API:

```
public class BaseApi
{
    public virtual string Get() 
    {
        return "";
    }
}
```

and its concrete implementations:

```
public class ApiX : BaseApi
{
    public override string Get()
    {
        return "Api_X";
    }
}

public class ApiZ : BaseApi
{
    public override string Get()
    {
        return "Api_X";
    }
}

public class ApiT : BaseApi
{
    public override string Get()
    {
        return "Api_T";
    }
}
```

Then this is `Parameter` class:

```
public class Parameter
{
    public string Parameter_1 { get; set; }
}
```

Then we need some place where we will store all API's that should be called. I think, we can create some very simple factory. This factory will have just one overridable method:

```
public abstract class ApiSimpleFactory
{
    public abstract IEnumerable<BaseApi> GetAll();
}
```

and its concrete implementations:

```
public class ApiXZSimpleFactory : ApiSimpleFactory
{
    public override IEnumerable<BaseApi> GetAll() =>
        new List<BaseApi>()
        {
            new ApiX(),
            new ApiZ(),
        };
}

public class ApiXZTSimpleFactory : ApiSimpleFactory
{
    public override IEnumerable<BaseApi> GetAll() =>
        new List<BaseApi>()
        {
            new ApiX(),
            new ApiZ(),
            new ApiT(),
        };
}
```

Now, we are ready to implementat Chain Of Responsibity pattern:

```
public abstract class ApiHandler
{
    private protected abstract IEnumerable<string> ParameterOptions { get; }

    private ApiHandler _nextApiHandler;

    public void SetSuccessor(ApiHandler nextVehicleHandler)
    {
        _nextApiHandler = nextVehicleHandler;
    }

    public virtual ApiSimpleFactory Execute(Parameter parameter)
    {
        if (_nextApiHandler != null)
            return _nextApiHandler.Execute(parameter);

        return null;
    }
}
```

and its concrete implementations:

```
public class XZApiHandler : ApiHandler
{
    private protected override IEnumerable<string> ParameterOptions => 
        new List<string> { "string1", "string2" };

    public override ApiSimpleFactory Execute(Parameter parameter)
    {
        if (ParameterOptions.Contains(parameter.Parameter_1))
            return new ApiXZSimpleFactory();

        return base.Execute(parameter);
    }
}

public class XZTApiHandler : ApiHandler
{
    private protected override IEnumerable<string> ParameterOptions =>
        new List<string> { "string3" };

    public override ApiSimpleFactory Execute(Parameter parameter)
    {
        if (ParameterOptions.Contains(parameter.Parameter_1))
            return new ApiXZTSimpleFactory();

        return base.Execute(parameter);
    }
}
```

And now we can execute our code:

```
ApiHandler chain = new XZApiHandler();
ApiHandler xztApiHandler = new XZTApiHandler();

chain.SetSuccessor(xztApiHandler);

Parameter parameter = new Parameter { Parameter_1 = "string3" };

ApiSimpleFactory apiFactory = chain.Execute(parameter);
IEnumerable<BaseApi> apiToBeExecuted = apiFactory.GetAll();
```